# Unable to start the container from docker image/ Its failing if we add CMD to start filebeat or fluentd agent

Tags: docker, kubernetes, eks

am unable to start the container from the docker image that builds from below Dockerfile It's failing if we add CMD to start filebeat or fluentd agent.

Dockerfile

```
#################################################
FROM node:12
#install pm2
RUN npm install pm2 -g
RUN apt update
#create dir and copy the code
RUN mkdir -p /home/devops/comera_registration_service/
WORKDIR  /home/devops/comera_registration_service/
COPY . .
#fluentd install
COPY fl.sh . 
RUN sh fl.sh
#install depend
RUN npm install
#start the app
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "ecosystem.config.js" ]
CMD ["/etc/init.d/td-agent", "start" ]  
#opening port
EXPOSE 3010
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text when you can just copy and paste the text instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `node:12` image has an [entrypoint script](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/ee74eb16cf7dd67d284030f30890fbf4e91da2b1/12/stretch/Dockerfile#L68-L69). When an `ENTRYPOINT` is specified, Docker will use the values in `CMD` as [parameters for this entrypoint command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd).

The parent image entrypoint can be disabled by adding the following to your Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT []
```

As a side note, when multiple `CMD` instructions are specified in a Dockerfile, only the last one will be set in the resulting image.

With the Dockerfile above and the parent entrypoint removed, `/etc/init.d/td-agent` will be PID 1 of the container. Since this is an init script, it will exit when it's done starting the daemon. When PID 1 is gone, the container will exit.

To run multiple programs inside a container, [a wrapper script or process manager is needed](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/). Note that this is generally not recommended. Eg. on Kubernetes the sidecar container pattern is preferred.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried as you told but when ever am giving CMD as starting fluentd agent it is exiting the container.
``` 
CMD ["/etc/init.d/td-agent", "start" ]
ENTRYPOINT []

Comment: Updated the answer to include running multiple processes. Looking at your specific use-case, you should probably not add fluentd to the existing container image. I would recommend to look into running fluentbit/fluentd as a sidecar container.

Comment: Thanks, I will try on that. will update

Comment: Hi , I have changed the application log from the customized path to /dev/stdout and it's resolved the issue.